# Using a Right Skew Distribution to judge Continuity of Care

Tags: distributions, skewness

I'm looking for help with what kind of metrics (Skewness?) I could use to assign a number value to a certain preferred situation.

Specifically, for nurses that do home care, patients always feel better when they are visited repeatedly by the same nurse.

So consider these cases for a patient getting visited by nurses.

```
                            Number of visits by each nurse
```

Patient 1:    10  8  2  1  1  1  1  1

Patient 2:    18  3  2

Patient 3:    8   8  2  1  1  1  1  1

Patient 4:    2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

Patient 5:    20

Since patient 5 was seen by only one nurse, their situation is best. But patient 2 isn't doing much worse. Patient 4 is doing the worst because they never got seen by the same nurse more than twice.

Thinking of these as distributions, I essentially want to score distributions better by how "heavy" they are on the left. Does anyone have any suggested reading or distribution types that this would apply to?

Comment: This needs an answer from medicine or psychology, not statistics! Why would it even suffice to summarize the experiences of the patients by counts--wouldn't the actual pattern of alternating nursing care from day to day matter? Although statistical theory and thinking can help you determine what kinds of scores might be meaningful and useful, they cannot tell you which scoring method to select.